# SPSS logistic regression acceptable equation

Tags: analytics, logistic-regression, spss

Does logistic regression work with a categorical dependent variable,  continuous and categorical independent variables?
Does it matter if the covariates are continuous or categorical? i keep getting this warning of redundancies which after i looked out for multicollinearity and take out the variables that are highly correlated i still get the warnings.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GD4K.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The procedure works with binary response or dependent variables, and independent variables can be scale or "continuous" or categorical. String independent variables are automatically categorical, while numeric ones have to be specific as categorical by clicking on the Categorical button and moving them from the source list to the target list in that sub-dialog box.

Redundancies are not indicative of just highly correlated variables, but actually perfect linear dependencies, typically among categorical variables. The procedure creates k-1 dummy or contrast-coded variables to represent a k-level categorical independent variable, with specific codings determined by your choice of contrast type(s). The codings are displayed in the Categorical Variables Codings table. If the status of every case on any of these variables can be determined by the values of any others (or any of the continuous variables), then that's a redundancy (a linear dependency). For continuous variables, the same is true, though this less common, usually occurring only if something like a copy of a variable gets included by mistake, or one or more variables are computed as linear combinations of others and all are included as independent variables.

Your screen shot doesn't show any independent variables specified as categorical, but I can't tell if there are others also used that might be. If not, then you could try running a linear regression model to diagnose the issue(s). Use the same dependent variable and independent variables and try the forced entry method (the default), and if there are linear dependencies among the predictors, at least one won't be included in the linear model.

One possibility for creation of dependencies is having more predictors than cases, which can unexpectedly happen if you have a lot of missing data, as logistic regression will drop any case missing on the dependent or any independent variables.